# Recovery mode device drivers not working in HTC Desire 616

Tags: adb, fastboot, bootloader, htc, usb-drivers

I have an HTC desire 616, bootloader locked, S-ON.
I am able to enter on recovery-mode but the device is not listed in ADB, though I have all latest drivers from Google, Windows and HTC.
I am able to enter in sideload mode, drivers are working and I have 3 choices and 3 installed but the signature check prevents me to install any sort of updates.

1. I think is still on the software and relies on drivers but I don't know what I can do further
2. Is it possible to flash a unlock_code.bin of zeros?

Kindly waiting your help

Answer (score 0):

Finally I might have a solution but I need your help guys. I need the images of all partitions (userdata, cache, system,expdb,rootm,blinkfeed, ebr2,logo, misc, sec_ro,seccfg,protect_s, protect_f, nvram, pro_info, ebr1, mbr, preloader) which is not a custom ROM but essentialy it is like a copy of your phone. I need to download them from someone who has the same firmware d616w and with his bootloader unlocked(I might be wrong about this last sentence). 
Then I will flash all of them on my device, I will turn my device into S-OFF if it is not already and manually change IMEI, MID, S/N and other phone infos. Hopefully it will work, otherwise I m gonna use it as a brick for constructions ahah.